# Why Include Record Key in WebAPI PUT Parameters

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

In all the *ASP.NET WebAPI* examples I have seen for implementing the `HTTP PUT` method, the record's key is passed as a separate parameter to the model updates.  For example:

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, UserEditViewModel model)
{
    // Look up existing record
    User user = await db.Users.FindAsync(id);
    // Apply changes
    // user.Name = model.Name;
    // Commit updated record to data store
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I am curious as to why this approach is used rather than to define the key value on the model and simplify the call?

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(UserEditViewModel model)
{
    // Look up existing record
    User user = await db.Users.FindAsync(model.UserId);
    // Apply changes
    // user.Name = model.Name;
    // Commit updated record to data store
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

In most cases that I can think of the View will require the `UserId` anyway, so I don't see how/why it would complicated the model from the View's perspective, but I am sure there must be a good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what level of RESTfulness we're talking about, I think it might be more about convenience. Looking at [Richardson's Maturity Model level 3](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3), the workflow could be something like this:

`GET /api/users/{id}`

Once the client navigates to a user, the server will have built the link uri, filling it with the unique resource identifier, so it could look something like this:

```
"api:user-edit": {
  "href": "http://apiname:port/api/user/{id}"
},
```

So the client will have to just do a

`PUT /api/users/{id}`

with the appropriate payload (which theoretically should be the resource in full, but more often than not the server will only choose to look at just a couple of fields - almost like a `PATCH`).

Comment: Thank you Alexandru, that makes sense of it.